# I was swapping my Golden INU for ETH and I saw the total was $136.00 but never showed up in my Metamask wallet

Tags: uniswap

I need help, I don't understand shy the eth was never transferred back to my MetaMask wallet after swapping it on Uniswap.  My address is:  0x995634A5926ba20811137353b0015987eF876244
I can't believe this was all taken.  The Uniswap website I was using is: https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap

If you could tell how to get any of it back, I revoked approval but I see nothing.  David

Comment: When I click on this contract: 0xD87996Ff3D06858BFC20989aEF50cc5FCD4d84ca I see $95.46 in ETH and wonder if that is mine?

Comment: From the transaction list you never interacted with Uniswap you directly transferred the tokens in this transaction `0x24e78ec0723dd9dbd5766e002a1c0c8f6721dc38bdeb52bd075673459327f1fe`. The tokens remain in that wallet `0x0317e045a63Fb681e87FFeC9Be7F140F79600bcB`.

Comment: How do I get them back to Metamask?

Comment: Only the owner of `0x0317e045a63Fb681e87FFeC9Be7F140F79600bcB ` can transfer the tokens. If that is not your address then you have lost them.